# Trying to update a table with a customer sales averaging column - Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

Trying to to write a query to add a column to a sales table in order to average sales amounts for individual customers. I have tried quite a bit, ultimately populating the column with a single value over all the rows (not what I need). I have about 75 customers with a total of hundreds of invoices. Coming up blank. Thanks for any advice or help.

```
ALTER TABLE t1
ADD AVG_AMOUNT NUMBER(9,2);
UPDATE
  SET AVG_AMOUNT = 
    (SELECT CAST(AVG(col1)AS FLOAT)
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY col2;
```

I tried this but get the same value for the whole column.

```
ALTER TABLE t1
ADD AVG_AMOUNT NUMBER(9,2);
UPDATE t1
SET AVG_AMOUNT = 
  (SELECT CAST(AVG(INVOICE_TOTAL)AS FLOAT)
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.customer_ID=t2.customer_ID
WHERE t1.customer_ID = t2.customer_ID
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `UPDATE` statement you do not calculate the `AVG` per customer but an `AVG` on all customers. Put the customer identification in the where clause. The `GROUP BY` option is not needed since the `AVG` column is the only column in the `SELECT` statement (see other reply by @_horse_with_no_name):

```
UPDATE t1
SET AVG_AMOUNT=(SELECT AVG(INVOICE_TOTAL)
                FROM   t1 a1
                where  t1.customer_ID = a1.customer_ID);
```

Comment: col2 is the customer ID, I somehow want to bind the column to the col1 (sales) value in the where clause? How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your second statement goes into the right direction, but you have a join too many in there, you don't need to join the table again. You just need a co-related sub-query (one that references the outer table without a join):

```
UPDATE t1
SET AVG_AMOUNT =  (SELECT AVG(INVOICE_TOTAL)
                   FROM t1 t2 -- note a different alias
                   where t1.customer_ID = t2.customer_ID);
```

Another option is to use the MERGE statement which might be faster:

```
merge into t1 
using (
  select customer_id, avg(invoice_total) as avg_invoice
  from t1
  group by customer_id
) x ON (x.customer_id = t.customer_Id) 
when matched then update
  set t1.avg_amount = x.avg_invoice;
```